# Image is not existing in document directory if I will run the app again using Swift 3

Tags: ios, image, swift3, nsdocumentdirectory

I am saving a camera image into my document directory. I am creating a document directory in my util class. Here below is my code :-

```
//Get Document Directory Path
func getDirectoryPath() -> String {
  let paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("Phss")
  return paths
}

//Create Directory
func createDirectory(){
  let fileManager = FileManager.default

  let paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("Phss")

  if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: paths){
    try! fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: paths, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
  }

  else{
    Helper.sharedInstance.Print("Already dictionary created." as AnyObject)
  }
}
```

After that I am saving image by name and some value (docAddedTime) and storing the path(imagePath) in my core data DB.

```
func saveImageDocumentDirectory(imageData : Data, docName : String) -> String {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let imagePAth = (getDirectoryPath() as NSString).appendingPathComponent("\(String(describing: docAddedTime!) + "_" + "\(String(describing: docName))").png")

    fileManager.createFile(atPath: imagePAth, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
    return imagePAth
}.
```

I am fetching image by image path which is saved in my local core data DB.

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let imagePAth = doc!.docPath! //Core Data DB Path of image

    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imagePAth) {
         imgView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePAth
       }
```

The problem is first time I am able to fetch image and is showing in my imageView but after that I will run the app again and I am trying to fetch image by this imagePath which is stored in my core data DB then it's not giving that file exist at this path.

Image is present at same Path but showing is not exits. I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Are you sure that in the second time, your image path is the same as the first time? Try to print it out

Comment: Yes.
And image is present in document directory.
But Not able to show.

Comment: Save the image to the documents/Phss directory... Store only the image *name* to your DB... Next time you launch the app, get the image *name* from your DB, append it to the documents/Phss directory, load the image.

Comment: @DonMag Right only.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you are building the app from Xcode, new folder is being created and files will be in the new folder.

Do not rebuild the app just close the app from simulator and start the app again from simulator itself.

Complete Path of your file will be like:

```
file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4FA96815-521B-4D84-B5C7-10697DE1908B/data/Containers/Data/Application/54CC678C-7E96-4DB6-83CC-6ECB506DC9BF/Documents/tmp.png
```

On the next build:

```
Application/54CC678C-7E96-4DB6-83CC-6ECB506DC9BF/Documents/
```

will be changed as:

```
Application/3F3093C6-2140-473B-8F99-A717AF162CDE/Documents/
```

where `3F3093C6-2140-473B-8F99-A717AF162CDE` is created by Xcode not you

Answer (score 0):

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: paths).appendingPathComponent("fileName")
```

You can try the above snippet. This one don't create a directory though, I would suggest first try to fetch straight from Documents directory, once its a success then create a directory and then store it.Let me know the exact scenario. What is the value of the path showing when running for the next time.

Comment: Actually I don't know why this is happening but I understood one thing is for fetching image I have to create same path again I mean I can't use CreData DB same Path.